# Why does this Jenkins Pipeline code not succeed?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

this is my situation: one of my projects consists of multiple subprojects, roughly separated as frontend and backend, which are at different locations in a subversion repository.

I extracted the `checkout` plugin into a function, that is already properly parameterized for the checkout:

```
def svn(String url, String dir = '.') {
    checkout([
        $class: 'SubversionSCM',
        locations: [[
            remote: url,
            credentialsId: '...'
            local: dir,
        ]],
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
    ])
}
```

That way, I was able to do the checkout by this means (simplified):

```
stage "1. Build"

parallel (
    "Backend": { node {
        svn('https://svn.acme.com/Backend/trunk')
        sh 'gradle build'
    }},

    "Frontend": { node {
        svn('https://svn.acme.com/Frontend/trunk')
        sh 'gradle build'
    }}
)
```

Checking out at the very same time lead to Jenkins having troubles with changeset xml files, as far as I could guess from the stacktraces.

Since I also want to reuse both the projects name and its svn url, I moved on to iterate over a map and checking out consecutively and just stashing the files in the first stage for the following parallel build-only stage:

```
stage "1. Checkout"

node {
    [
        'Backend':  'https://svn.acme.com/Backend/trunk',
        'Frontend': 'https://svn.acme.com/Frontend/trunk', 
    ].each { name, url ->
        // Checkout in subdirectory
        svn(url, name)
        // Unstash by project name
        dir(name) { stash name }
    }
}

stage "2. Build"
// ...
```

Somehow Jenkins' pipeline does not support this, so I used a simple for-in loop instead:

```
node {
    def projects = [
        'Backend': '..'
        // ...
    ]

    for ( project in projects ) {
         def name = project.getKey()
         def url  = project.getValue()

         svn(url, name)
         dir(name) { stash name }
    }

    project = projects = name = url = null
}
```

That doesn't work as well and exits the build with an Exception: `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`. As you can see, I set every property to null, because I read somewhere, that this prevents that behaviour. Can you help me fix this issue and explain, what's exactly going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a known Jenkins bug of the for in-loop:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27421

But there is also a known bug for .each style loops

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481

So currently it seems like you cannot iterate over Maps in Jenkins Pipelines. I suggest creating a list as a workaround and iterate over it with the "classic loop" style:

```
def myList = ["Backend|https://svn.acme.com/Backend/trunk", "Frontend|https://svn.acme.com/Frontend/trunk"]

for (i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
  //get current list item : myList[i] and split at pipe | ->escape pipe with \\
  def (name, url) = myList[i].tokenize( '\\|' )
  //do operations
  svn(url, name)
  dir(name) { stash name }
}
```

Comment: This is quite annoying, since debugging pipeline script errors in Jenkins seems to be impossible. But thanks!